# How to prove that the area of a shape is independent of the choice of axes?

Tags: calculus, area

Suppose we have some shape in a plane, and we want to find its area using calculus.

I set my $x$ and $y$ axes arbitrarily. They are perpendicular to each other.

I can calculate the area of the region using a standard double integral, slicing up the area into rectangles with sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes.

$$A = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(\int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)}dy\right)dx$$

Now if I rotate my axes (still remaining perpendicular to each other) but leave the shape unchanged, and calculate the integral the same way but with the new $x$ and $y$ axes and new $x$ and $y$ bounds... I'm looking for a proof that the area will turn out the same.

Comment: The area is the same because you're not changing the shape. If the result of the integral changes, that means you did something wrong in the transformation. What you want to ask (at least according to my personal philosophy on this matter) is "how do I change the bounds as I rotate the coordinate system, so that I'm still integrating over the same region?" That's not trivial. Even for a square, that's a bit tricky.

Comment: "The area is the same because you're not changing the shape". But this is exactly what I'm asking about. Why is this true? I know we take it for granted, but I'm looking for a proof that this is true.

Comment: Because the basic intuitive notion we have of area requires that it is unaffected by rotating it (the distinction between rotating the coordinate system and rotating the region of interest is basically non-existent). As you say, we take it for granted. A rigorous definition of "area" that changes as you rotate it does not, in my opinion, deserve the name "area". If the integral had changed by rotations, then the integral wouldn't calculate area. It would calculate something, but that something wouldn't be area.

Comment: ok. But how do I prove that the procedure I described in my post satisfies this intuitive notion of area (ie that it doesn't change)?

Comment: Well, then you need a formal definition of area first. If you want to define area as an integral, fine. But you need to decide on what **exactly** area is. If you define area as something else, then you need to show that the integral gives the same result. If you define area as an integral (or you can do this anyway), then you need to take a very good look at the exact relationship between the bounds of the region in one coordinate system compared to the other. And as I said, even for something as simple as a square, that's a bit tricky.

Comment: @Arthur, yes the problem I'm finding is that the definitions of area I'm seeing are defined as an integral. ie: it's not that the area is defined as something independent first that the integral later happens to calculate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113607/discussion-between-ameet-sharma-and-arthur).

Comment: I don't like to discuss in chat. It creates an expectation to be available immediately, and it doesn't give notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Just use integration by substitution ($u$-substitution).

- Two things to note about rotations. First, every rotation transformation $\mathbf{R}_\theta(x,y)$ has a matrix determinant of 1 for all $x$ and $y$. You can prove this to yourself using:
  $$\mathbf{R}_\theta(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos{\theta}&\sin{\theta}\\-\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\=\left\langle x\cos{\theta}+ y\sin{\theta},\;-x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}\right\rangle$$

  Second, the total derivative of every rotation is itself. You can prove this using the above equation; it is true in general because a rotation is a *linear* coordinate transform. You can represent it as a matrix multiplication.
- The substitution formula says that if $\varphi(\mathbf{u})$ is an invertible and appropriately smooth transformation in some region $U$, then:

  $$\int_{\varphi(U)} f(\mathbf{v})d\mathbf{v} = \int_{U} f(\varphi(\mathbf{u}))\cdot\left|\det(D\varphi)(\mathbf{u})\right| d\mathbf{u}$$
- For your particular case, you have a shape $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ whose integral you want to calculate. You have some rotation $\mathbf{R}_\theta$ which transforms $S$ into a rotated version of itself $\widehat S$. Because we are just integrating to get area, let $f$ denote the (boring) constant function $f(x)=1$. Applying the variable substitution formula,

$$\begin{align*}\iint_{\widehat S} dx^\prime dy^\prime &= \iint_{\mathbf{R}_\theta(S)} f(x^\prime,\,y^\prime) dx^\prime dy^\prime\\&=\iint_S f\left(\mathbf{R}(x,y)\right) \cdot\left|\det(D\mathbf{R})(x,y)\right|dx\,dy\\  
&=\iint_S 1 \cdot\left|\det(D\mathbf{R})(x,y)\right|dx\,dy & \{f \text{ is constant}\}\\ 
&=\iint_S 1 \cdot\left|\det(\mathbf{R})(x,y)\right|dx\,dy & \{\text{rotation is linear}\}\\ 
&=\iint_S 1 \cdot\left|1\right|dx\,dy & \{\det=1\}\\ 
&=\iint_S \; dx\, dy
\end{align*} $$

- We have proven that the area will be the same before and after. The two key features we used were that (1) the derivative of a linear transformation (such as a rotation) is equal to the function itself: $D_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}$, and (2) the Jacobian determiant of a rotation is equal to 1 for every $x$ and $y$. (This is really the key part; the Jacobian determinant tells you how the infinitesimal area of $dx\,dy$ is scaled up by the transformation. If the Jacobian were 2 everywhere, it would double the area. If the Jacobian varied with $x$ and $y$, the transform might shrink some areas and grow others. Because it's 1 everywhere, the infinitesimal area remains unaltered at all points.)
- Note that we can use this same argument to show that *reflections* preserve area as well; they're linear transformations with a determinant of -1. Thanks to the absolute value signs in the variable substitution formula, the same reasoning applies.  Similarly for a *glide transform*, which is a reflection followed by a rotation.

Comment: Thanks. This answers everything for me.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this can be proven using Green's Theorem.

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/GreensTheorem.aspx

So we can write the area of a region as a line integral around the boundary:

$$A = \oint_C xdy = -\oint_C ydx$$

So if we rotate our axes clockwise by $\theta$ radians:

$$x_{\text{new}} = \cos(\theta)x - \sin(\theta)y$$
$$dy_{\text{new}} = \sin(\theta)dx + \cos(\theta)dy$$

$$A_{\text{new}} = \oint_C x_{\text{new}}dy_{\text{new}} $$

$$A_{\text{new}} = \oint_C (\cos(\theta)x - \sin(\theta)y)(\sin(\theta)dx + \cos(\theta)dy) $$

$$A_{\text{new}} = \left(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\oint_C xdx\right) + \left(\cos^2(\theta)\oint_C xdy\right)$$$$ - \left(\sin^2(\theta)\oint_C ydx\right)- \left(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\oint_C ydy\right)$$

First and last integrals go to $0$.

$$A_{\text{new}}= \left(\cos^2(\theta)\oint_C xdy\right) - \left(\sin^2(\theta)\oint_C ydx\right)$$

$$A_{\text{new}} = \left(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\right)A$$

$$A_{\text{new}} = A$$

Green's theorem also shows that an area can be divided arbitrarily into subregions. The sum of the small line integrals adds up to a line integral around the whole region (edges being shared by regions cancel each other out). This demonstrates that the area integral is additive.

I would like to see other answers as this feels like overkill to use Green's Theorem prove a basic idea about integrals and areas.

Comment: nice answer   ...................        +1

Answer (score 1):

Transformations that preserve distances in a metric space are called [isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) and the only isometries of Euclidean spaces are rotations, translations, reflections or some composition of those operations. Rotations and reflections are non-trivial but thankfully they're easily characterized as they're linear transformations. Conceptually this proof relies on the geometric interpretation of the determinant as a signed volume of a parallellpiped and the fact that distance preserving transformations will also preserve areas, just like in your integral. This means they'll have determinant of $\pm 1$. All that's left to prove is that every such matrix preserves distances. Lets get started.

First, we'll use column vectors and for two vectors $x$ and $y$ we'll use matrix multiplication to represent the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = x^Ty$ with $x^T$ the transpose of $x$. This allows us to write the Euclidean metric as $||x|| = \sqrt{x^Tx}$. Now we're interested in matrices that act on $x$ by multiplication but preserve distances, that is to say we're interested in an an $A$ such that $||Ax||=||x||$ and by squaring both sides we can simplify this to $(Ax)^TAx = x^Tx$. Since $(Ax)^T = x^TA^T$ this implies that $x^TA^TAx=x^Tx$ and so we must have that $A^TA=I$, the identity matrix. This means $A$ must be an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) and in particular, has determinant $\pm 1$ because $\det A = \det A^T$ and $\det(A^TA) = \det A^T \det A$ we have that $\det A^TA = \det I = 1$ and so $\det A = \pm 1$. Since every matrix of this form has this property they are all isometries and we're done. Note that I never had to mention the number of dimensions either so this is the case for $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you want to work over the complex numbers you replace the transpose with the conjugate transpose but the ideas are the same.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this: "the fact that distance preserving transformations will also preserve areas, just like in your integral." is partly what I want a proof for. Specifically, that the "integral" satisfies our intuitive area axioms (like it doesn't change with rotations... and sum of the area of the subdivisions in any way will add up to the total area).

Comment: @AmeetSharma I proved it immediately after I made that claim. Do you want proof that the determinant is a signed volume? Or do you want a proof that Reimann sums are rectangular regions? I don't know what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the integral of a region bound by two curves is independent of our choice of axes. If we rotate our axes, then the division of the region into Riemann rectangles will be different from the first time. I'd like a proof that the integrals come out the same.

Comment: @AmeetSharma If the integral exists it's unique and it doesn't matter how you partition the area at all. I can prove this too I'll see if I can get to it tonight.

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I mean. Proof that an area integral is independent of the choice of partitioning you use.

Comment: What if the region is not convex so some of the slices have more than one part.

Comment: @martycohen all that matters is that the measure (area, volume, hypervolume) of the intersection of each of the partitions is zero and that the measure of the largest partition converges to zero. If a partition has disjoint regions eventually the refinements will split them into separate regions.

Answer (score 1):

The result you want is that if $E$ is a "shape in the plane", then $A(E)= A(R(E)+ v),$ where $R$ is a rotation, and $v\in \mathbb R^2.$ In other words, area is an invariant under rotations and translations. The problem you're having may be due to problems with defining "area" rigorously. The ideas in Lebesgue measure theory make short work of this, once you have it, but of course you are probably not in a measure theory course.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some self-study on measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

We require to show that the standard definition of area of a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a double integral wrt a Cartesian coordinate system is independent of the particular Cartesian coordinate system chosen. This is a special case of a more general result on surface integrals in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The proof of the latter given below uses the Riemann integral for multivariable functions on $\mathbb{R}^p$ as described in [ERA] and an associated notion of 'content' in $\mathbb{R}^p$ which formalizes the intuitive ideas of length, area, and volume and extends them to $\mathbb{R}^p$. Reduced to the present special case the more general theorem states that $\displaystyle{\int_D 1 = \int_{D'} 1}$, where the integral is the [ERA] integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D$ is the region expressed in the original Cartesian coordinate system and $D'$ is the same region expressed in the second Cartesian coordinate system. To evaluate these integrals in practice a theorem equating them to iterated integrals would normally be applied with the region of integration split up if necessary. The region $D$ can be any compact set which 'has content' (see (8) & (9) below). The [ERA] definition of content for $\mathbb{R}^p$ means it is defined as the limit of an appropriate sequence of Riemann sums, and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ these progressively become closer to the true intuitive area/volume as $n \rightarrow \infty$, however proof is required that for a given region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ these sequences converge to the same limit irrespective of the Cartesian coordinate systems that they are based on.

The following notions and theorems from [ERA] on differentiation and integration of functions on $\mathbb{R}^p$ are used below :

1. For $f : D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$, $Df(c)$ denotes the linear function from $\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ which is the derivative of $f$ at cluster point $c \in D$ and $J_f(c) = \left[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right]$ denotes the Jacobian of $f$ at $c$. The term $C^1$ when applied to a multivariable function means it has continuous 1st partial derivatives.
2. If $f : D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ is differentiable at the cluster point $c \in D$ and if partial differentiation is well-defined in all coordinate directions at $c$ (ie. $c$ is a cluster point in all these directions) then all partial derivatives of $f$ at $c$ exist and the derivative $Df(c) = J_f(c)$. (Follows from [ERA, Theorem 20.6, p232] on directional differentiation).
3. If $f : G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ where $G$ is open and $f$ is $C^1$ on $G$ then $f$ is differentiable on $G$. (Also applies if $G$ is a non-zero content interval in $\mathbb{R}^p$). [ERA, 20.7, p233]
4. (Chain Rule) The composition $h = g \circ f$ of two differentiable multivariable functions is differentiable with derivative $Dh(x) = Dg(f(x)) \circ Df(x)$. [ERA, 20.9, p235]
5. (Composition of $C^1$ functions) The composition $h = g \circ f$ of two $C^1$ functions defined on open sets is also $C^1$, and $J_h(x) = J_g(f(x)) \cdot J_f(x)$. Follows from (2), (3) and (4) above and using fact that sums, products, and compositions of continuous functions are continuous. (As in (3) above instead of an open set we may have a non-zero content interval).
6. If $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is an open set and $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a $C^1$ function with $\mathrm{det}\,J_f \neq 0$ throughout $G$ then $f(G)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^p$. (Follows from Open Mapping Theorem in [ERA, 21.9, p256]).
7. (Inverse of $C^1$ function) If $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is an open set and $C^1$ function $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is injective and has $\mathrm{det}\,J_f \neq 0$ throughout $G$ then $f^{-1} : f(G) \rightarrow G$ is $C^1$  and $J_{f^{-1}}(f(x)) = J_f(x)^{-1}\ \forall\ x \in G$. (Unlike in (3) and (5) above we may not have a non-zero content interval instead of an open set, for example the function which converts spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates whose inverse has a discontinuity similar to the complex argument and log functions). Follows from Inversion Theorem [ERA, 21.10, p256] and (6) above.
8. A subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is defined to have 'zero content' (abbreviated 'ZC') if $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists$ a finite compact interval cover $\{J_1, \ldots, J_n \}$ of $A$ with $A(J_1) + \cdots + A(J_n) < \epsilon$, where $A(J)$ denotes the 'content' (ie 'volume') of compact interval $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$. Note this is a distinct concept from 'measure zero'. [ERA, Definition 24.1, p317].
9. A bounded subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is said to 'have content' (abbreviated 'HC') if the boundary $B(D)$ (ie closure less interior) of $D$ has zero content. Many regions encountered in practice have this property. [ERA, Definition 24.12, p325]
10. 'Content' $A(D)$ is defined for any bounded HC set $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ by $A(D) = \displaystyle{\int_{\overline{D}}} 1$. (The criterion of 'bounded HC' ensures this integral exists). [ERA, Definition 24.12, p325]
11. If $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is compact HC then any continuous function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ is integrable on $D$. (This is the 2nd Integrability Theorem in [ERA, 24.11, p324]).
12. (Preservation of Compact HC) If $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is open and $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a $C^1$ function with $\mathrm{det}\,J_f \neq 0$ throughout $G$ then for any compact HC set $D \subseteq G$ the set $f(D)$ is compact HC. [ERA, Lemma 24.23, p333].
13. (Transformation of Integrals Theorem) If $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is open and $\phi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is $C^1$ with $\mathrm{det}\,J_{\phi} \neq 0$ throughout $G$ then if $D \subseteq G$ is compact HC and and $f : \phi(D) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $\phi(D)$ is compact HC and :
    $$
    \int_{\phi(D)} f = \int_D (f \circ \phi) \cdot | \mathrm{det}\,J_{\phi} |
    $$
    [ERA, 24.26, p335]

Note : the Riemann integral for $\mathbb{R}^p$ defined in [ERA, §24, p320] is defined natively on $\mathbb{R}^p$ and is written $\int_D f$, but below we use the notation $\int_D f(x, y, z)$ without the $dx\,dy\,dz$ to avoid confusion with iterated integrals which are not required in the proof below. The $x, y, z$ merely indicate the notation being used for the points in the region $D$.

### Theorem

Let $S$ be a surface in Euclidean space expressible wrt right-handed Cartesian coordinate system $CS$ as $S = \{ (x, y, s(x, y)) : (x, y) \in G \}$, where $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $s : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function. Let $D \subseteq G$ be compact HC and $f : S_D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function where $S_D = \{ (x, y, s(x, y)) : (x, y) \in D \}$ and denote by $I$ the surface integral of $f$ over $S_D$ wrt $CS$ :
$$
I = \int_{S_D} f = \int_D f(x, y, s(x, y)) \sqrt{s_x^2 + s_y^2 + 1}
$$
Suppose $CS'$ is any other right-handed Cartesian coordinate system for the Euclidean space such that if $S' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is $S$ expressed in $CS'$ coordinates then :

(i) The surface $S'$ has 1-1 projection onto the $x'y'$-plane of $CS'$ (ie. $S'$ can be expressed in 'Monge form' within $CS'$).

(ii) The tangent plane to $S'$ is never 'vertical' in $CS'$, ie. never perpendicular to the $x'y'$-plane of $CS'$.

Then $S' = \{ (x', y', s'(x', y')) : (x', y') \in G' \}$ for some open $G' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $C^1$ function $s' : G' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and if $f'$ denotes the function $f$ in $CS'$ coordinates then $\mathrm{dom}\, f' = S'_{D'} = \{ (x', y', s'(x', y')) : (x', y') \in D') \}$ where $D' \subseteq G'$ is compact HC and the surface integral $I'$ of $f'$ over $S'_{D'}$ given by :
$$
I' = \int_{S_{D'}} f' = \int_{D'} f'(x', y', s'(x', y')) \sqrt{{s'_{x'}}^2 + {s'_{y'}}^2 + 1}
$$
is equal to $I$.

### Proof

$CS'$ can be obtained by a 3D rotation of $CS$ about the origin followed by a pure translation of the result. Let $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the transform from $CS$ coords to $CS'$ coords, so $\alpha(\underline{\mathbf{r}}) = A \cdot \underline{\mathbf{r}} + \underline{\mathbf{a}}$, where $\underline{\mathbf{a}}$ is a constant vector and $A$ is a right-handed orthogonal matrix with its rows (and columns) orthonormal sets:
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
\underline{\mathbf{u}} \\
\underline{\mathbf{v}} \\
\underline{\mathbf{w}}
\end{array} \right] \hspace{2em} \mbox{say, where $\underline{\mathbf{u}}$, $\underline{\mathbf{v}}$, $\underline{\mathbf{w}}$ are the unit vectors of $CS'$ wrt $CS$.}
$$
Then $S' = \alpha(S)$. Define $G' = \{ (x', y') : \exists\ z'\ \mbox{such that } (x', y', z') \in S' \}$. By $CS'$ property (i), $\forall\ (x', y') \in G'$, $z'$ is unique and thus we can define $s' : G' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as this unique $z'$. Then $S' = \{ (x', y', s'(x', y')) : (x', y') \in G' \}$.

Now $(x, y) \in G \Rightarrow \alpha(x, y, s(x, y)) \in \alpha(S) = S'$. Define $\beta(x, y)$ to be the 1st 2 coords of $\alpha(x, y, s(x, y))$ so $\beta : G \rightarrow G'$. Then $s'(\beta(x, y)) = $ 3rd coord of $\alpha(x, y, s(x, y))$. We then have the following properties of $\beta$ for $(x, y) \in\ G$ :

(a) $s'(\beta(x, y)) = \underline{\mathbf{k}}_3 \cdot \alpha(x, y, s(x, y))$

(b) $\alpha(x, y, s(x, y)) = (\underline{\mathbf{i}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\ \underline{\mathbf{j}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\ s'(\beta(x, y)))$

(c) $\beta(x, y) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right] \alpha(x, y, s(x, y))$. Then by ERA (5), $\beta$ is $C^1$ on $G$, since $\alpha$ and $s$ are $C^1$.

(d) $\beta$ is in general non-linear since $s$ is in general non-linear. $\beta$ is linear if $S$ is a planar surface.

(e) It is readily checked that $\beta : G \rightarrow G'$ is a bijection.

(f) $J_{\beta} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} u_1 + u_3s_x & u_2 + u_3s_y \\ v_1 + v_3s_x & v_2 + v_3s_y \\ \end{array} \right]$ and $\mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta} = -\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}$ where $\underline{\mathbf{n}} = (s_x, s_y, -1) = $ normal to surface $S$ in $CS$-coords, since from (c) above $\beta$ is a composition of three $C^1$ functions and so by ERA (5) we have :
$$
J_{\beta} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} \underline{\mathbf{u}} \\ \underline{\mathbf{v}} \\ \underline{\mathbf{w}} \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ s_x & s_y \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \underline{\mathbf{u}} \\ \underline{\mathbf{v}} \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ s_x & s_y \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} u_1 + u_3s_x & u_2 + u_3s_y \\ v_1 + v_3s_x & v_2 + v_3s_y \\ \end{array} \right]
$$
and,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta} & = & (u_1 + u_3 s_x)(v_2 + v_3 s_y) - (u_2 + u_3 s_y)(v_1 + v_3 s_x) \\
& = & \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2 & u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3 & u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} -s_x \\ -s_y \\ 1 \end{array} \right] \\
\therefore\ \mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta} & = & -\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}
\end{eqnarray*}
since $J_{\alpha}$ is a right-handed orthogonal matrix, so that $\underline{\mathbf{w}} = \underline{\mathbf{u}} \times \underline{\mathbf{v}}$.

(g) By $CS'$ property (ii) the $z'$-axis and $\underline{\mathbf{n}}$ can never be perpendicular, therefore since these vectors are respectively $\underline{\mathbf{w}}$ and $\underline{\mathbf{n}}$ wrt the coordinate system $CS$, by (f) above we must have $\mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta} \neq 0$ on $G$.

(h) By ERA (6) and (e) and (g) above it follows that $G' = \beta(G)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(i) By ERA (12) and (g) above if we define $D' = \beta(D)$ then $D'$ is compact HC. We show below that for this $D'$ we have $\mathrm{dom}\, f' = S'_{D'} = \{ (x', y', s'(x', y')) : (x', y') \in D') \}$.

(j) From ERA (7) and (c) and (g) above and it follows that $\beta^{-1} : G' \rightarrow G$ is $C^1$.

To show $s' : G' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$, from $\beta$ property (a) above we have (substituting $(x, y) = \beta^{-1}(x', y')$ into (a)), for any $(x', y') \in G'$ :
$$
s'(x', y') = \underline{\mathbf{k}}_3 \cdot \alpha(\underline{\mathbf{i}}_2 \cdot \beta^{-1}(x', y'),\; \underline{\mathbf{j}}_2 \cdot \beta^{-1}(x', y'),\; s(\beta^{-1}(x', y')))
$$
where each of $\alpha$, $\beta^{-1}$, and $s$ are $C^1$ functions on their respective open domains, thus $s'$ as a composition of $C^1$ functions is also $C^1$.

Now consider the continuous function $f'$ which is $f$ expressed in terms of $CS'$. By definition $f' = f \circ \alpha^{-1}$ and $\mathrm{dom}\, f' = \{ (x', y', z') : \alpha^{-1}(x', y', z') \in \mathrm{dom}\, f \} \therefore$ since $\mathrm{dom}\, f = S_D$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x', y', z') \in \mathrm{dom}\, f' & \Leftrightarrow & \alpha^{-1}(x', y', z') \in S_D \\
& \Leftrightarrow & (x', y', z') = \alpha(x, y, s(x, y))), \hspace{2em} \mbox{for some } (x, y) \in D \\
& \Leftrightarrow & (x', y', z') = (\underline{\mathbf{i}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\; \underline{\mathbf{j}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\; s'(\beta(x, y))) \\
& & \mbox{for some } (x, y) \in D, \mbox{by $\beta$ property (b)} \\
& \Leftrightarrow & (x', y') = \beta(x, y) \mbox{ and } z' = s'(x', y'), \hspace{1em} \mbox{for some } (x, y) \in D \\
& \Leftrightarrow & (x', y') \in D' \mbox{ and } z' = s'(x', y'), \hspace{1em} \\
& & \mbox{from the above definition of } D' = \beta(D) \\
& \Leftrightarrow & (x', y', z') \in S'_{D'} \hspace{1em} \mbox{from the definition of } S'_{D'}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\mathrm{dom}\, f' = S'_{D'}$ as required.

Now consider the continuous functions :
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x, y) & = & f(x, y, s(x, y)), \hspace{2em} \mbox{for } (x, y) \in D \\
g'(x', y') & = & f'(x', y', s'(x', y')), \hspace{2em} \mbox{for } (x', y') \in D'
\end{eqnarray*}
which appear within $I$ and $I'$ :
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x, y) \in D \Rightarrow g'(\beta(x, y)) & = & f'(\underline{\mathbf{i}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\; \underline{\mathbf{j}}_2 \cdot \beta(x, y),\; s'(\beta(x, y))) \\
& = & f'(\alpha(x, y, s(x, y))), \hspace{2em} \mbox{from $\beta$ property (b)} \\
& = & f(x, y, s(x, y)), \hspace{2em} \mbox{since } f' = f \circ \alpha^{-1} \\
& = & g(x, y)
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $g' \circ \beta = g$ on $D$.

Since $D' = \beta(D)$ we have :
\begin{equation}
I' = \int_{\beta(D)} g'(x', y') \sqrt{{s'_{x'}}^2 + {s'_{y'}}^2 + 1}
\end{equation}
$\therefore$ by ERA (13) (Integral Transform) :
\begin{equation}
I' = \int_D(g' \circ \beta)(x, y) \sqrt{s'_{x'}(\beta(x, y))^2 + s'_{y'}(\beta(x, y))^2 + 1} \; \cdot \; |\mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta}(x, y)|
\end{equation}
where the term $(g' \circ \beta)(x, y) = g(x, y)$, as appears in $I$.

Thus to show $I' = I$ it suffices to show that :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{det}\,J_{\beta}(x, y)^2 \cdot s'_{x'}(\beta(x, y))^2 + \mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta}(x, y)^2 \cdot s'_{y'}(\beta(x, y))^2 + \mathrm{det}\,J_{\beta}(x, y)^2 & = & s_x^2 + s_y^2 + 1, \\
\forall\ (x, y) \in D & & \hspace{5em} (1)
\end{eqnarray*}

But applying ERA (5) to $\beta$ property (a) for $(x, y) \in G$ we have :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}   s'_{x'}(\beta(x, y)) & s'_{y'}(\beta(x, y)) \end{array} \right] \cdot J_{\beta}(x, y) & = & \mbox{Jacobian of } \underline{\mathbf{k}}_3 \cdot \alpha(x, y, s(x, y)) \\
& = & \mbox{3rd row of Jacobian of } \alpha(x, y, s(x, y)) \\
& = & \mbox{3rd row of } J_{\alpha} \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ s_x & s_y \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \underline{\mathbf{u}} \\ \underline{\mathbf{v}} \\ \underline{\mathbf{w}} \end{array} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ s_x & s_y \end{array} \right] \\
& = & \left[ \begin{array}{cc} w_1 + w_3 s_x & w_2 + w_3 s_y \end{array} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} s'_{x'}(\beta(x, y)) & s'_{y'}(\beta(x, y)) \end{array} \right] & = & \left[ \begin{array}{cc} w_1 + w_3 s_x & w_2 + w_3 s_y \end{array} \right] \cdot J_{\beta}(x, y)^{-1} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\mathrm{det}\,J_{\beta}(x, y)} \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} w_1 + w_3 s_x & w_2 + w_3 s_y \end{array} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} v_2 + v_3 s_y & -u_2 - u_3 s_y \\ -v_1 -v_3 s_x & u_1 + u_3 s_x \end{array} \right] \\
& & \hspace{0em} \mbox{from $\beta$ properties (f) and (g),} \\
\therefore\ \mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta}(x, y) \cdot s'_{x'}(\beta(x, y)) & = & (w_1 + w_3 s_x)(v_2 + v_3 s_y) - (w_2 + w_3 s_y)(v_1 + v_3 s_x) \\
& = & (v_2 w_3 - v_3 w_2) s_x + (v_3 w_1 - v_1 w_3) s_y - (v_1 w_2 - v_2 w_1) \\
& = & (\underline{\mathbf{v}} \times \underline{\mathbf{w}}) \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}} \\
\mbox{and } \mathrm{det}\, J_{\beta}(x, y) \cdot s'_{y'}(\beta(x, y)) & = & (w_1 + w_3 s_x)(-u_2 - u_3 s_y) + (w_2 + w_3 s_y)(u_1 + u_3 s_x) \\
& = & (w_2u_3 - w_3u_2)s_x + (w_3u_1 - w_1u_3)s_y -(w_1u_2 - w_2u_1) \\
& = & (\underline{\mathbf{w}} \times \underline{\mathbf{u}}) \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}
\end{eqnarray*}

But since $A$ is a right-handed orthogonal matrix transform we have $\underline{\mathbf{v}} \times \underline{\mathbf{w}} = \underline{\mathbf{u}}$ and $\underline{\mathbf{w}} \times \underline{\mathbf{u}} = \underline{\mathbf{v}}$ and from $\beta$ property (f) we have $\mathrm{det}\,J_{\beta}(x, y) = -\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}$. Thus LHS of (1) equals :
$$
(\underline{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2 + (\underline{\mathbf{v}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2 + (\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2
$$
But since $\{ \underline{\mathbf{u}}, \underline{\mathbf{v}}, \underline{\mathbf{w}} \}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underline{\mathbf{n}} & = & (\underline{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}) \, \underline{\mathbf{u}} + (\underline{\mathbf{v}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}) \, \underline{\mathbf{v}} + (\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}}) \, \underline{\mathbf{w}} \\
\mbox{so } |\underline{\mathbf{n}}|^2 & = & \underline{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}} = (\underline{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2 + (\underline{\mathbf{v}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2 + (\underline{\mathbf{w}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{n}})^2
\end{eqnarray*}
and thus LHS of (1) equals $|\underline{\mathbf{n}}|^2$, ie. $s_x^2 + s_y^2 + 1$, as required.

**References**

[ERA] Robert G. Bartle (1964), The Elements of Real Analysis, John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: wow! it's pretty long answer!!